# How to compress dynamic responses in sails/express using npm compression package

Tags: node.js, express, npm, compression, sails.js

While using **npm compression** package in sails project I observed that responses from server getting gzipped but I have some API's whose response is not getting gzipped/compressed.

As per documentation **app.use(compression())** itself compresses all the responses but I can't find any response header as "content-encoding" : "gzip" in API's that contains JSON Data in response.

Following are the headers that I'm receiving in my response:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://xxxxxxxxxx.com
access-control-expose-headers: 
content-length: 312
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Wed, 28 Nov 2018 10:44:56 GMT
etag: W/"138-SIGn/Sj6rEAdXMhpUah0Xw"
status: 200
vary: X-HTTP-Method-Override, Accept-Encoding
x-powered-by: Sails <sailsjs.org>
```

Here **content-encoding : 'gzip'** is missing.

Following is my custom middleware which I have used in config/http.js file

```
/**
 * HTTP Server Settings
 * (sails.config.http)
 *
 * Configuration for the underlying HTTP server in Sails.
 * Only applies to HTTP requests (not WebSockets)
 *
 * For more information on configuration, check out:
 * http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.http.html
 */
var compression = require('compression')
module.exports.http = {

  /****************************************************************************
  *                                                                           *
  * Express middleware to use for every Sails request. To add custom          *
  * middleware to the mix, add a function to the middleware config object and *
  * add its key to the "order" array. The $custom key is reserved for         *
  * backwards-compatibility with Sails v0.9.x apps that use the               *
  * `customMiddleware` config option.                                         *
  *                                                                           *
  ****************************************************************************/
  customMiddleware : function(app){
    app.use(compression())
  }
};
```

Help me out if any one knows how to compress such responses, I tried the very same thing in native express application also but facing the same issue.

Comment: Solution : Well I figured out about this tried possible things to do compression from app level but nothing worked as a workaround I used Apache server as a mediator which works perfectly for compressing dynamic responses.